# How to update textfield.text value in custom TableViewCell from UIPickerView

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I want UITextFiled.text in custom UITableViewCell to be updated when I choose some value from UIPickerView.

If you take a look on the picture I tap to UITextField in custom UITableViewCell and UIPickerView shows up. Then I choose number and tab "Done" button. But I do not know how to pass selected value from UIPickerView to my custom UITableViewCell where is my UITextFiled.text.

Can anyone help me out please?Thanks

[The screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziGQP.png)

**Custom Cell**

```
class JamkaTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, pickerChangedDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var jmenoHraceLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var parTextField: UITextField!

    func onPickerChanged(val: String) {
        self.parTextField.text = val
        print(self.parTextField.text)
    }
 }
```

**View Controller**

```
import UIKit

protocol pickerChangedDelegate {
    func onPickerChanged(val: String)
}

class JamkaViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var vzdalenostLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var jmenoLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var parJamkyLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var jamkaView: UIView!

    var picker: UIPickerView!
    var karta:Karta = Karta.init()
    var index = 0
    var vzdalenost:Int!
    var jmenoJamky:String = ""
    var parJamky:Int!
    var pocetKopu:[String] = []
    var hrac:Hrac!
    var delegate: pickerChangedDelegate? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        vzdalenostLabel.text = "\(self.vzdalenost)"
        jmenoLabel.text = self.jmenoJamky
        parJamkyLabel.text = "\(self.parJamky)"

        //Vypocitat pocet kopu a trestných bodů
        pocetKopu(self.parJamky)

        //Jamka view
        self.jamkaView.layer.cornerRadius = 5

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.karta.seznamHracu.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! JamkaTableViewCell

            self.hrac = self.karta.seznamHracu[indexPath.row]

            //Vybiratko na pary
            self.picker = UIPickerView.init()
            self.picker.delegate = self
            self.picker.dataSource = self
            self.picker.backgroundColor = svetleSeda

            let pickerToolbar = UIToolbar()
            pickerToolbar.barStyle = .Default
            pickerToolbar.sizeToFit()
            pickerToolbar.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()

            let hotovoTlacitko = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Done, target: self, action: #selector(JamkaViewController.skrytPickerView))

            pickerToolbar.setItems([hotovoTlacitko], animated: true)
            pickerToolbar.userInteractionEnabled = true

            cell.parTextField.inputView = self.picker
            cell.parTextField.inputAccessoryView = pickerToolbar
            cell.jmenoHraceLabel.text = self.hrac.jmeno

            print(cell.parTextField.text)

        return cell

    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return self.pocetKopu.count
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return self.pocetKopu[row]
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        delegate?.onPickerChanged(self.pocetKopu[row])
        print("did select \(self.pocetKopu[row])")
    }

    func pocetKopu(parJamky: Int) -> [String] {

        let maximalniPocetKopu = (3*parJamky)

        for i in 1...maximalniPocetKopu {

            let str = String(i)
            self.pocetKopu.append(str)

        }

        //Trestne body
        let trestneBody = String(4*parJamky)
        self.pocetKopu.append(trestneBody)

        return self.pocetKopu

    }

    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        let pointInTable:CGPoint = textField.superview!.convertPoint(textField.frame.origin, toView:self.tableView)
        var contentOffset:CGPoint = self.tableView.contentOffset
        contentOffset.y  = pointInTable.y
        if let accessoryView = textField.inputAccessoryView {
            contentOffset.y -= accessoryView.frame.size.height
        }
        self.tableView.contentOffset = contentOffset
        return true;
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, 0), animated: true)
        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, 0), animated: true)
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

    func skrytPickerView() -> () {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement didSelectRow of pickerView like this:

```
//create delegate in controller that contains picker
protocol pickerChangedDelegate{
    func onPickerChanged(val: String)
}


class vc: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate{
    @IBOutlet var picker: UIPickerView!

    //your view controller ....
    //....


    var delegate: pickerChangedDelegate? = nil
    var items = ["1", "2", "3"]

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        //this will send picker value through protocol to your cell
        delegate?.onPickerChanged(items[row])
    }
}



//use delegate where you want data
class customCell: UITableViewCell, pickerChangedDelegate{
    @IBOutlet weak var myText: UITextField!

    //Cell setup
    //....
    //....


    func onPickerChanged(val: String) {
        myText.text = val
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for advice. I am using custom cell, however I am a beginner and I do not understand "you can handle this in cell itself and send data with a protocl to view controller of ypur table" could you please provide me any piece of code how could I achieve it or explain it more? Thank you very much

Comment: @MiroslavPurtík i update the code and how you can use the protocol to get your data in your cell.

Comment: thank you for answer I did everything according to your code but delegate?.onPickerChanged(self.pocetKopu[row]) will never execute :( Check my code above please. Thank you very very much

Answer (score 0):

```
class vContoller: UIViewController ,  UITextFieldDelegate , UIPickerViewDataSource , UIPickerViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet var accountNo: UITextField! 

var accountNoArray: [String] = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

 accountNoArray = ["1","2"]
 self.accountNo.delegate = self
}




func pickerCode(text: UITextField){



    let picker: UIPickerView
    picker = UIPickerView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 200, view.frame.width, 300))
    picker.backgroundColor = .whiteColor()
    picker.showsSelectionIndicator = true
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.dataSource = self

    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
    toolBar.translucent = true
    toolBar.sizeToFit()

    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "donePicker")
    let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "canclePicker")

    toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
    toolBar.userInteractionEnabled = true

    if text.tag == 2
    {
        self.tagMaster = 2
        accountNo.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
        accountNo.inputView = picker
        //accountNo.text = "  " + accountNoArray[0]
    }
}

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int{

    return 1

}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{
    var count: Int = 0
    if self.tagMaster == 2
    {//accountNo
        count = accountNoArray.count
    }
    return count
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    var stro:String = ""
    if self.tagMaster == 2
    {//accountNo
        stro = accountNoArray[row]
    }
    return stro

}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    if self.tagMaster == 2
    {//accountNo
        accountNo.text = "  " + accountNoArray[row]


    }
}

func donePicker(){

    accountNo.resignFirstResponder()
    if self.tagMaster == 2
    {
        accountNo.resignFirstResponder()

    }
}

func canclePicker(){

    if self.tagMaster == 2
    {
        accountNo.resignFirstResponder()

        accountNo.text = "  " + accountNoArray[selectedRowForAccNoAndLbrCode]
    }

}


func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {

    pickerCode(textField)
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {

    pickerCode(textField)
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: Thanks I will try and let you know :)